# current passing in primary circuit of transformer

Tags: electricity

When the secondary circuit is open ,why does the self induction  found in primary coil would resist the flow of current in it? whereas in the small examples that I have taken in my studies from coils and others, the self induction would just delay but it won't stop current from flowing .. if i am wrong with some information , please correct for me ...

Comment: If the secondary is open (and all stray capacitance between its leads are negligible) then only in the primary can you have current flowing. There is nothing else, right?

Answer (score 0):

A transformer is essentially two coupled inductors and, thus, the equations are

$$v_p = L_1 \frac{di_p}{dt} + M \frac{di_s}{dt}$$

$$v_s = M \frac{di_p}{dt} + L_2 \frac{di_s}{dt}$$

where

$$M = k\sqrt{L_1L_2}$$

If the secondary is open, the secondary current is zero (constant) so

$$\frac{di_s}{dt} = 0$$

Thus,

$$v_p = L_1 \frac{di_p}{dt}$$

In phasor notation

$$V_p = j\omega L_1 I_p$$

or

$$\frac{V_p}{I_p} = Z_p = j \omega L_1$$

So, when the secondary is open, the *impedance* looking into the primary (in this simple model) is proportional to the primary inductance.

For an ideal transformer, the coupling is perfect and the primary and secondary inductances are 'infinite' thus, an open secondary implies zero primary current.

Comment: I have no idea about phasor notation so , starting from this part i can't get anything :/